# react, useEffect: Can you use global variable as a dependent variable?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
window.data = {}

useEffect(() => {
// do something
}, [window.data])
```

Does the above code makes sense?

since window.data is global, it won't be different on renders, and the effect won't execute?

Comment: just test it? should work ... but "Global variables are considered an anti-pattern in almost any programming language"

Comment: wel, I find it not working (although I'm setting a Webview's window.test from RN) and wasn't sure .. ya I could have tested it :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, that won't work. Effect could only be triggered when component is rerendered and dependencies change. Changing global variables won't cause a rerender, so the effect won't run.

Comment: I'm using `useLayoutEffect` for it, and I stored the `window.myGodDamnedVariable` into another variable, This causes the ESLint to shutup about violating hook dependencies.
I'm still looking for a better way tho, I am forced to do this for now

Comment: That doesn't really help. That exact piece of code doesn't work, but what does? What's a pattern that would let us use a global variable (and an "update" hook)?

Answer (score -1):

It actually causes a re-render for me. It works, but I think it is an anti-pattern